# Unable to Provide Routing correctly in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-routing

I am creating a login application where the user has to login and after the login, if the user is valid he needs to be redirected to the given page.

The login and redirecting works.

**Problem:**
In the Login page, my side navigation menu is also visible. It should only be displayed in the other routes.

**App.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule, MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'Details', component: DetailsComponent },
  { path: 'UserConfig', component: UserconfigComponent },
  {path:'',redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'},
  {path:'**',redirectTo:'/login',pathMatch:'full'},

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    CardDetailsComponent,
    UserconfigComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    Ng4LoadingSpinnerModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**App.component.html**

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <app-header class="header"></app-header>

  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav  #sideNav opened="false" mode="side">
      <ul>
        <li routerLinkActive="active current"><a  routerLink="/CardDetails">Card Details</a ></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/UserConfig">User Config</a></li>
      </ul>  
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-icon (click)="sideNav.toggle()" class="home_btn">
      Menu
    </mat-icon>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  </mat-sidenav-container>

 <app-footer></app-footer>

</div>
```

**Login.component.ts**

```
Loginuser(data) {
      const dataObj = {Email: data.Email, Password: data.Password};
      this.serv.getLogin(dataObj).subscribe(res => {
        if (res.id == 0) {
          alert('please check the username or password');
        } else {
          console.log(res);
          localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(res));
          this.router.navigate(['/CardDetails']);
        }
      });

    }
```

Here on the login page itself, the menu is displaying somewhere I made a mistake I don't know where it is

Answer (score 1):

Because your `<mat-sidenav-container>` is outside of the `<router-outlet>` container, it is always displayed, no matter what route is active.

You have two possibilities:

1) Only show the `<mat-sidenav>`, `<mat-icon>` if the user is logged in. You could for example check, if the AuthToken in your localStorage is there and valid. `*ngIf="isUserLoggedIn"`

2) Your `AppComponent` template has just a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in it, nothing else. Then, you have a second `<router-outlet>` in the `UserRouterComponent` template underneath, this time with the `<side-nav>`. The routes that should display the side-nav are children of the `UserRouterComponent`. Your route configuration would be something like:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'user', component: UserRouterComponent  children: [
    { path: 'details', component: DetailsComponent },
    { path: 'config', component: UserconfigComponent }
  ]};
```

Copy the template from `app.component.html` in `user-router.component.html`.

Your `app.component.html`:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: I'm not storing any tokens here I'm getting a response like userid,roleid,email I'd etc . Could u share me plunker or stakblitz

Comment: I would recommend going with solution two anyway. Have a look at this video, Deborah Kurata addresses your problem exactly: https://youtu.be/66XR8EnFepA?t=42m22s

Answer (score 1):

> You can intercept route changes, the following way:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    this.navigationInterceptor(event);
  });
}

navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
  if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
    this.currentUrl = event.url;

    // Do something with the url

    // For url login, set this.showSideNav = false

    // For others, sset this.showSideNav = true
  }
}
```

> Whenever navigation starts, you can check for the route name:

1. Then Login Page, set `this.showSideNav = false`
2. For Other routes, set `this.showSideNav = true`